# Basic Activity does not match between tutorial and what I actually create with Arctic Fox

Tags: android-studio

I am not new to programming but new to Android Studio.  Using Arctic Fox and working through the tutorials @ developer.android.com most everything has been straightforward.  My question is in regards to creating a Basic Activity.  The tutorial here: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-available-resources#2 shows a newly created project using Basic Activity:

[image: developer.android.com]

However, when I create new project with Basic Activity, I get two screens with a button to toggle between them.  Also, the title says "First Fragment" or "Second Fragment" depending on which screen I am on:

[image: my AVD]

My question is this:  Is the tutorial just outdated (March 2021) for using Arctic Fox OR am I just overlooking something really stupid?

Not worried about the application titles or any other widgets as I will learn how to change those as I progress through my lessons.  Just wondering why what I created is so different from the lesson itself.

Comment: @MikeM.  Thanks for confirming my suspicion!  I will just plug along with my lessons for now and not worry further about this issue as I will learn how to change everything to my liking down the road.

Comment: No problem. I wasn't entirely correct about the "no notes" thing, and accidentally deleted that comment when trying to edit, but the rest of what I said was right. Just FYI. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will chalk this up to the tutorial being out of date from the newest version of Android Studio (Arctic Fox) that I am using.  I have noticed several differences in the tutorials along the way between what I have in Arctic Fox and what the tutorials present but for the most part they are pretty easy to figure out and stay on track.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the tutorial is not outdated.
You could have created two fragments i.e. First Fragment and Second Fragment and attached those to your MainActivity.
Thats why on button click, fragments are switching.
Please share your MainActivity code for more clarification

Comment: What I show is what was created out of the box.  I did not change anything from creating the initial Basic Activity.